# Past 26 weeks and their respective week number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

If I run the query today (21 Aug 2012) I want to get this result set:

[image]

[...]

[image]

To get this I'm using the following but it seems over-complicated. Can this be simplified?

```
;WITH Numbers_cte([number]) 
        AS 
        ( --return the numbers from 1 to 182 i.e 26*7
        SELECT DISTINCT number 
        FROM Master..spt_values 
        WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 182
        )
,MultipleSeven_cte([number], [multiple])
        AS 
        ( --divide the number series by 7 and return integers 
        SELECT 
            [number]
            ,[multiple] = (([number]-1) / 7)+1
        FROM Numbers_cte
        ) 
,Today_cte([Today])
        AS 
        ( --return the last date in the table or use GETDATE for this example
        SELECT [Today]=CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112))
        ) 
,EquivDates_cte([multiple],[number],[Today], [EquivDates])
        AS
        ( 
        SELECT 
             x.multiple
            ,x.number
            ,y.Today 
            ,[EquivDates] = DATEADD(DAY,-(182-x.number),y.[Today]) 
        FROM MultipleSeven_cte x, Today_cte y
        )                   
SELECT 
        multiple
        ,number
        ,[EquivDates] 
FROM EquivDates_cte
```

Comment: Is there no DATE_FORMAT function that includes a week / day number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do this:

```
select (number/7)+1 as multiple ,
        number+1 as number,
        dateadd(dd,-(182-number),GETDATE()) as EquivDates
from    master..spt_values 
where   type='P'
and     number<182
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/3484)

Comment: 'number/7<=25' ... is inspired!

Comment: although rather than `number/7<=25` why not just have `[number] < 182` ?

Comment: @whytheq: thats better .. I have updated my answer.. I put number/7<=25 becoz, the question says "past 26 weeks"... :)

Answer (score 2):

I've got it down to:

```
  select distinct 
        number,
        [week] = ((number-1) / 7)+1,
        olddate = DATEADD(DD,
                        -1 * (182-number+1),
                        DATEADD(dd,0,(DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()))))
  from master..spt_values
  where number between 1 and 182
```

Comment: I realise that this is a working solution, yet some "nits" drew my attention: 1) since the OP is using SQL Server 2008, you could just do with `CAST(GETDATE() AS date)` instead of `DATEADD(... DATEDIFF(...) ...)`; 2) the two nested DATEADD calls could easily be combined into one; 3) usually it's `DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(...), 0)`, not `DATEADD(DD, 0, DATEDIFF(...))` (we calculate the day difference between a specific date and the date `0` (whatever it may be) and add it back to the date `0`, *not* 0 days to a date that is internally represented as an integer equal to the day difference).

Comment: Good point about `date`. Have changed this. Re 2, could have condensed them into 1, but not sure it would have been as easy to work out the logical process.